# Laravel4 - Sessions are disappearing on simultaneous requests

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I have a kind of shopping basket and I am keeping the content as separate sessions for various reasons.

The problem is, when I send simultaneous requests to the following add function, Laravel's loosing previous, unrelated/different sessions and keeping the last one but it's working fine if I wait for the previous process to finish.

I think the problem is Laravel's session management method, it tries to keep everything in a single file or single field in the database. If so, I don't see any solution for this but here's the code;

```
public function add($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4){

    sleep(2);

    $results = DB::select("CALL ...(?, ?, ?, ?)", array($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4));
    $sessionName = "basket-item-$param1-$param2-$param3-$param4";
    $selectionIDs = array();
    $status = null;

    if(!Session::has($sessionName)){
        if($results){
            foreach($results as $result){
                $selectionIDs[] = $result->selection_id;
            }
        }

        if($selectionIDs) Session::put($sessionName, $selectionIDs);
        $status = 'new';
    }

    return array('count' => $this->count(), "has_session_this" => Session::has($sessionName), 'session_name' => $sessionName, 'status' => $status);
}
```

Count is item `count`, `has_session_this` is the response of `Session::has($key)` and the `session_name` is the `$key`

```
ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=1, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-7894628-21494", more...}

ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=2, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-14834686-21494", more...}

ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=3, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-21132688-21494", more...}

ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=4, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-3500057-21494", more...}
```

That's the expected result and if I don't wait for the response;

```
ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=1, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-7894628-21494", more...}

ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=1, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-14834686-21494", more...}

ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=1, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-21132688-21494", more...}

ADD TO BASKET RESPONSE : Object { count=1, has_session_this=true, session_name="basket-item-1-256-3500057-21494", more...}
```

Any help, any idea is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like transaction problem. Does Laravel not lock the session when you open it? I don't have any experience with Laravel so I don't know. If the session is locked, and you must wait until it's unlocked you can never get these concurrency issues. Locking is how the default sessions handlers work in PHP.

Comment: I was wondering the same and it seems it doesn't do that. The last thing I want to do was dealing with these but it's inevitable I guess. Thanks for the comment by the way.

Comment: @Halcyon - Laravel uses Symfony sessions - which lock sessions to prevent this exact issue. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your logic. Has nothing to do with sessions.

If the previous functions have not completed - then the count start at 1. Only if/when the previous function is complete would the count increase.

But you are using `$this->count()` - so it looks like it might be getting the count on the current session object when you started the function - not the updated count.

If you want to ensure a correct count increment - you need to use

`Cache::increment('key')`

And your cache driver needs to be Memcache or Redis for it to work. [See docs for more info](http://laravel.com/docs/cache#increments-and-decrements).

Comment: That's why I am using unique session keys. See the comments below.

Comment: What do you mean - how does a unique session key matter? If the first function has not run - the count will still be 1 no matter what. The count does not increase until the first function has completed.

Comment: p.s. laravel is obviously not losing the session if "has_session_this" is true.

Comment: Laravel keeps all the session key-value pairs in the same file (like PHP itself) but the session class (filesystem class actually) does not lock this file for writing. As a result, different instance of the same function overwriting the same file with their own data and this is the result. This is a purely a transaction issue as Halcyon suggested.

Comment: No its not. Count() is the number of rows in the database? Correct? You are not even adding count() to your session. All that is happening is the "count()" is being retrieved while there is still only 1 row in the database. Then you are running multiple queries simultaneously - but you are not getting a new count() - you are using the old count() from the original request. This has NOTHING to do with sessions.

Comment: Sorry but you sound like you have no idea what are you talking about. Nope, it doesn't the row count, it's a session count. A number of keys in the session array in this case. And I am getting those responses after the process done. So it should add up unless there's a transaction problem as described above. Cache class != Session class btw.

Comment: "Cache class != Session class btw" - yes - exactly - session class will not solve your problem. Cache class will. Read the docs that I provided.

Comment: p.s. I thought your add() function was in your model. I just realised it is in your session. But the answer is the same - only Cache counter will give you want you want - then insert the cache counter into your session.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange the reason a cache counter would work is because you assume the `increment` is atomic, and if it is then it's fine. Locking is generally a way to ensure things are atomic. It might be that the locking issue is indeed in the queries, as you suggest. Tim do you think you can verify this?

Comment: In Laravel Cache increment IS atomic. It is also why Cache increment cannot be used on "file" and "database" cache drivers - only Redis and Memcache - because they provide atomic incrementation.

Comment: My point is: there are ways to ensure other operations are atomic too, with locking. Using an atomic cache operation here is a clever workaround, but it doesn't solve the underlying concurrency issue.

Comment: Laravel uses Symphony session handlers. Symphony provides session locking automatically. http://garethmccumskey.blogspot.fr/2009/10/php-session-write-locking-and-how-to.html

Comment: I think the problem is with "$this->count()" - I dont understand what content "$this" is being used. There is no count() available on the Session facade. @Tim - you said " it's a session count" - but how are you running that? Is it a function you made yourself? Where is add() defined? Inside the session class? Or elsewhere?